# Adding same values to an array

Tags: python, list

I have this array:

```
            countOverlaps = [numA, numB, numC, numD, numE, numF, numG, numH, numI, numJ, numK, numL]
```

and then I condense this array by getting rid of all 0 values:

```
            countOverlaps = [x for x in countOverlaps if x != 0]
```

When I do this, I get an output like this:
[2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1]

Which is what it should, so that makes sense. Now I want to add values to the array so that each number adds itself to the array the number of times it appears.

Like this:

Original:
[2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1]

What I want: [2,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,1,1]

Is something like this possible in python?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem individually. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to count the number of times a thing occurs.  If so, do you really want to append the number of occurrences to a list?  Seems a dictionary would be more appropriate.  If so, your output would be this `{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Please check below:

```
>>> a = [2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1]
>>> [b for b in a for _ in range(b)]
[2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much

Comment: This could be rewritten like `[k for k in a for _ in range(k)]`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using list comprehension. So far you had:

```
countOverlaps = [10,25,11,0,10,6,9,0,12,6,0,6,6,11,18]
countOverlaps = [x for x in countOverlaps if x != 0]
```

This gives us all non=0 numbers. Then we can do what you want with the following code:

```
mylist = [number for number in list(set(countOverlaps)) for i in range(0, countOverlaps.count(number)) ]
```

This turns 'mylist' into the following output, which is what you're after:

```
[6, 6, 6, 6, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 18, 25]
```